# run a gitlab-ci stage only if two tags exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to run a stage only if a commit was tagged with "qa-passed" AND "integration-passed" tags (for example).
any suggestions?

```
image: node:latest
stages:
  - only-after-qa-integration

Stage1:
  stage: only-after-qa-integration
  script:
    - ...
  <tags?only>?:
...
```

Comment: `qa-passed` seems rather unusual for a git tag. Could you elaborate a little more on what tags do you mean?

Comment: I would like the deploy-to-production stage to run only if deploy to qa was run, and someone tagged it as "passed"- meaning someone tested the qa version (in the qa env) and marks it as ready for prod.

Comment: So you're deleting the old "passed" tag and force pushing a new "passed" tag to repo? I'm still not sure if you're don't mean the issue labels. Why not merge the release-candidate branch to master instead and deploy master?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty clear explanation about it in their [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags) .

Comment: thanks. I experimented with that, but the "tags" use case is for runners, not stages

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I'll look it up :^)